How can I add keyboard support to my calculator program in ReactJS?
I am making a calculator program in ReactJS and am trying to add keyboard support to my program (as in the keyboard can be used instead of the buttons on the screen). Currently, the onscreen buttons are functioning perfectly, however, when integrating the keyboard, I am having quite a bit of difficulty in getting it to function properly. I am trying to make my program recognize key presses (such as numbers or operators) using an Event Listener, and then perform the calculations corresponding to the pressed keys using "if"-statements to differentiate key presses. The two functions I have used for the onscreen buttons (which are functioning porperly are handleClick and handleNewClick, and the two functions I have used for the keyboard support are handleKeyDown and HandleNewKeyDown (which are not functioning properly).
Buttons:
    const handleClick = (label) => {
        if(isThisANumber(label) || label === '.') {
            if (label === '.' && currentOperand.includes('.')) {
                return;
            }
            if (label === '.' && currentOperand.length === 0) {
                setCurrentOperand(['0', '.']);
            } else {
                setCurrentOperand([...currentOperand, label]);
            }
        } else if (isThisAnOperation(label)) {
            if (currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                        setCurrentOperand([]);
                        setOperation(label);
                    }
            } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation(label);
            }
        } else if (label === '=') {
            if(previousOperand.length > 0 && currentOperand.length > 0) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                  setCurrentOperand([result.toString()]);
                  setPreviousOperand([]);
                  setOperation(null);
                  setIsAnswer(true);
                }
            }
        } else if (isThisASpecialOperation(label)) {
            if (label === 'x²') {
                setCurrentOperand([(Math.pow(Number(currentOperand.join('')), 2)).toString()]);
                setIsAnswer(true);
            } else if (label === '√') {
                setCurrentOperand([(Math.sqrt(Number(currentOperand.join('')))).toString()])
                setIsAnswer(true)
            } else if (label === '+/−') {
                if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setCurrentOperand([(currentOperand.join('') * -1).toString()]);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            let result;
            const currentValue = Number(currentOperand.join(''));
            
            if (label === 'x²') {
                result = Math.pow(currentValue, 2);
            } else if (label === '√') {
                result = Math.pow(currentValue, 1 / 2);
            } else if (label === '+/−') {
                result = currentValue * -1;
            }

            setCurrentOperand([roundNumber(result)]);
        } else if (label === 'AC') {
            setPreviousOperand([]);
            setCurrentOperand([]);
            setOperation(null);
        } else if (label === 'DEL') {
            setCurrentOperand(currentOperand.slice(0, -1));
        } else if (label === 'MC') {
            setMemory(0);
        } else if (label === 'MR') {
            setCurrentOperand([memory.toString()]);
            setIsAnswer(true);
        } else if (label === 'M+') {
            setMemory(memory + parseFloat(currentOperand.join('')));
        } else if (label === 'M-') {
            setMemory(memory - parseFloat(currentOperand.join('')));
        } else if (label === 'MS') {
            setMemory(parseFloat(currentOperand.join('')));
        }
    };

    const handleNewClick = (e, label) => {
        if(e.target.classList.contains('digit-button')) {
            setCurrentOperand(prevCurrentOperand => [prevCurrentOperand.splice(0,currentOperand.length), label])
            setIsAnswer(false);
           // return console.log('Digit Button Pressed', label);
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('clear-button')) {
            setCurrentOperand([]);
            setPreviousOperand([]);
            setOperation([]);
            setIsAnswer(false);
           // return console.log('Clear Button Pressed', label);
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('delete-button')) {
            setCurrentOperand([]);
            setPreviousOperand([]);
            setOperation([]);
            setIsAnswer(false);
           // return console.log('Delete Button Pressed', label);
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('decimal-button')) {
            setCurrentOperand(prevCurrentOperand => [prevCurrentOperand.splice(1,currentOperand.length), ["0."]])
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('operation-button')){
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('semi-special-operation-button')) {
            setIsAnswer(false);
        }
    };

Keyboard:

    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key) {
            //console.log(`Key: ${e.key} with keycode ${e.keyCode} has been pressed`);
        }

            if(isThisANumber(e.key) || e.key === '.') {
                if (e.key === '.' && currentOperand.includes('.')) {
                    return;
                }
                if (e.key === '.' && currentOperand.length === 0) {
                    setCurrentOperand(['0', '.']);
                } else {
                    setCurrentOperand([...currentOperand, e.key]);
                }
            } else if (e.keyCode === 107 || e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 187) {
                if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                    const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                        setCurrentOperand([]);
                        setOperation('+');
                    }
                } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('+');
                }
            } else if (e.keyCode === 109 || e.keyCode === 189) {
                if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                    const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                        setCurrentOperand([]);
                        setOperation('−');
                    }
                } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('−');
                }
            } else if (e.keyCode === 111 || e.keyCode === 191) {
                if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                    const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                        setCurrentOperand([]);
                        setOperation('÷');
                    }
                } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('÷');
                }
            } else if (e.keyCode === 88 || e.keyCode === 106) {
                if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                    const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                        setCurrentOperand([]);
                        setOperation('×');
                    }
                } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('×');
                }
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 54 || e.keyCode === 38) {
                if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                    const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                        setCurrentOperand([]);
                        setOperation('^');
                    }
                } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('^');
                }
            } else if (e.keyCode === 187 || e.keyCode === 13) {
                if(previousOperand.length > 0 && currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                    setCurrentOperand([result.toString()]);
                    setPreviousOperand([]);
                    setOperation(null);
                    setIsAnswer(true);
                    }
                }
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 50) {
                console.log('currentOperand before is: ', currentOperand);
                if(currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setCurrentOperand([(Math.pow(Number(currentOperand.join('')), 2)).toString()]);
                    setIsAnswer(true);
                }

                let result;
                const currentValue = Number(currentOperand.join(''));
                result = Math.pow(currentValue, 2);
                setCurrentOperand([roundNumber(result)])
                if (roundNumber(result)) {
                    console.log('roundNumber(result) is: ', roundNumber(result));
                }
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 51) {
                console.log('currentOperand before is: ', currentOperand);
                if(currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setCurrentOperand([(Math.pow(Number(currentOperand.join('')), 1 / 2)).toString()]);
                    setIsAnswer(true);
                }

                let result;
                const currentValue = Number(currentOperand.join(''));
                result = Math.pow(currentValue, 1 / 2);
                setCurrentOperand([roundNumber(result)])
                if (roundNumber(result)) {
                    console.log('roundNumber(result) is: ', roundNumber(result));
                }
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 78) {
                if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                    setCurrentOperand([(currentOperand.join('') * -1).toString()]);
                } else {
                    return;
                }

                let result;
                const currentValue = Number(currentOperand.join(''));
                result = currentValue * -1;
                setCurrentOperand([roundNumber(result)])
            } else if (e.keyCode === 67) {
                setPreviousOperand([]);
                setCurrentOperand([]);
                setOperation(null);
            } else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
                setCurrentOperand(currentOperand.slice(0, -1));
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 76) {
                setMemory(0);
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 82) {
                setCurrentOperand([memory.toString()]);
                setIsAnswer(true);
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 80) {
                setMemory(memory + parseFloat(currentOperand.join('')));
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 81) {
                setMemory(memory - parseFloat(currentOperand.join('')));
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 77) {
                setMemory(parseFloat(currentOperand.join('')));
            }
    }

    const handleNewKeyDown = (e) => {
        if(isThisANumber(e.key)) {
            setCurrentOperand(prevCurrentOperand => [prevCurrentOperand.splice(0,currentOperand.length), e.key])
            setIsAnswer(false);
            //return console.log('Digit Button Pressed', e.key);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 67) {
            setCurrentOperand([]);
            setPreviousOperand([]);
            setOperation([]);
            setIsAnswer(false);
           // return console.log('Clear Button Pressed', e.key);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
            setCurrentOperand([]);
            setPreviousOperand([]);
            setOperation([]);
            setIsAnswer(false);
            //return console.log('Delete Button Pressed', e.key);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 190) {
            setCurrentOperand(prevCurrentOperand => [prevCurrentOperand.splice(1,currentOperand.length), ["0."]])
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 107 || e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 187){
            if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('+');
                }
            } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                setCurrentOperand([]);
                setOperation('+');
            }
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 109 || e.keyCode === 189) {
            if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('−');
                }
            } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                setCurrentOperand([]);
                setOperation('−');
            }
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 111 || e.keyCode === 191) {
            if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('÷');
                }
            } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                setCurrentOperand([]);
                setOperation('÷');
            }
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 88 || e.keyCode === 106) {
            if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('×');
                }
            } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                setCurrentOperand([]);
                setOperation('×');
            }
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 54 || e.keyCode === 38) {
            if(currentOperand.length > 0 && previousOperand.length > 0 && operation) {
                const result = calculateResult(previousOperand, currentOperand, operation);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    setPreviousOperand([result.toString()]);
                    setCurrentOperand([]);
                    setOperation('^');
                }
            } else if (currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setPreviousOperand(currentOperand);
                setCurrentOperand([]);
                setOperation('^');
            }
            setIsAnswer(false);
        } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 50) {
            console.log('currentOperand before is: ', currentOperand);
            if(currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setCurrentOperand([(Math.pow(Number(currentOperand.join('')), 2)).toString()]);
                setIsAnswer(true);
            }

            let result;
            const currentValue = Number(currentOperand.join(''));
            result = Math.pow(currentValue, 2);
            setCurrentOperand([roundNumber(result)])
            console.log('roundNumber(result) is: ', roundNumber(result));
        } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 51) {
            console.log('currentOperand before is: ', currentOperand);
            if(currentOperand.length > 0) {
                setCurrentOperand([(Math.pow(Number(currentOperand.join('')), 1 / 2)).toString()]);
                setIsAnswer(true);
            }
            let result;
            const currentValue = Number(currentOperand.join(''));
            result = Math.pow(currentValue, 1 / 2);
            setCurrentOperand([roundNumber(result)])
            if (roundNumber(result)) {
                console.log('roundNumber(result) is: ', roundNumber(result));
            }
        }
    }


The issue I am experiencing is occurring when squaring and square-rooting numbers using the keyboard. When a number is first squared, the correct answer is displayed. Then, when taking the square-root of the given number, the correct answer is displayed. However, when trying to square the resulting number again, the square root of the first number will be displayed. For example, squaring "3" will return "9" (correct), square-rooting the given "9" will return "3" (correct), squaring the given "3" will return "81" (incorrect), square-rooting the given "81" will return "3" (incorrect). I have provided some console logs to display this happening:
currentOperand before is:  ['3']
roundNumber(result) is:  9
currentOperand before is:  [9]
roundNumber(result) is:  3
currentOperand before is:  [9]
roundNumber(result) is:  81
currentOperand before is:  [9] 

It appears as if the squaring and square-rooting functions for the keyboard are not updating the state properly by performing the calculations, but rather storing the initial calculations' returned numbers as values.
I also have tried having the key presses run the handleClick function, however my attempt at this only allowed for one calculation to be run using the keyboard, after which the keys would become unresponsive and would require the page to be refreshed, or the buttons to be clicked again to reset them. This is my attempt at this:
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key) {
            //console.log(Key: ${e.key} with keycode ${e.keyCode} has been pressed);
        }

            if(isThisANumber(e.key) || e.key === '.') {
                handleClick(e.key)
            } else if (e.keyCode === 107 || e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 187) {
                handleClick('+');
            } else if (e.keyCode === 109 || e.keyCode === 189) {
                handleClick('−')
            } else if (e.keyCode === 111 || e.keyCode === 191) {
                handleClick('÷');
            } else if (e.keyCode === 88 || e.keyCode === 106) {
                handleClick('×');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 54 || e.keyCode === 38) {
                handleClick('^');
            } else if (e.keyCode === 187 || e.keyCode === 13) {
                handleClick('=');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 50) {
                handleClick('x²');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 51) {
                handleClick('√');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 78) {
                handleClick('+/−');
            } else if (e.keyCode === 67) {
                handleClick('AC');
            } else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
                handleClick('DEL');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 76) {
                handleClick('MC');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 82) {
                handleClick('MR');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 80) {
                handleClick('M+');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 81) {
                handleClick('M-');
            } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 77) {
                handleClick('MS');
            }
    }

    const handleNewKeyDown = (e) => {
        if(isThisANumber(e.key)) {
            handleNewClick(e, e.key);
            //return console.log('Digit Button Pressed', e.key);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 67) {
            handleNewClick(e, 'AC');
           // return console.log('Clear Button Pressed', e.key);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
            handleNewClick(e, 'DEL');
            //return console.log('Delete Button Pressed', e.key);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 190) {
            handleNewClick(e, '.');
        } else if (e.keyCode === 107 || e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 187){
            handleNewClick(e, '+');
        } else if (e.keyCode === 109 || e.keyCode === 189) {
            handleNewClick(e, '−');
        } else if (e.keyCode === 111 || e.keyCode === 191) {
            handleNewClick(e, '÷');
        } else if (e.keyCode === 88 || e.keyCode === 106) {
            handleNewClick(e, '×');
        } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 54 || e.keyCode === 38) {
            handleNewClick(e, '^');
        } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 50) {
            handleNewClick(e, 'x²');
        } else if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 51) {
            handleNewClick(e, '√');
        }
    }

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

With the info provided is difficult to give you an exact answer, but I could give you some advice in order to achieve the thing you need
Try to decouple the logic that execute the operations and the source of information (clicks or keydowns)
This could be achieved collecting the clicks or keydown and transform the data with another function this response could be sent to the function that will calculate and persist your operations
Apart from that I still can't get why is it necessary to have handleClick and handleNewClick
I will be leaving you a sketch of my idea, try to refactor and probably you will get where is the problem.
With this approach you will be able to focus on the code that is persisting the data and state and forget about the other code, currently is too coupled that is imposible to read and try to find the problem


Thank you very much for your response. :) The reason why I have two functions each for both clicks and keydowns is to solve another problem I was having… When a calculation is performed and the “=“ button is pressed, “isAnswer” is switched from ‘false’ to ‘true’. This is so after a calculation is made, the clear button does not need to be pressed to start another calculation, but rather simply pressing a digit button will clear the displayed number. Is there a way I could simply make the keydown functions to run the click functions with the corresponding labels?

from my point of view you don't have to couple keydown and click, the thing that you need to do is get the key or the click and translate it to a common language or symbol that is going to be send to the function that will update the state, so you need a function that will take that job (get the symbol from click or keydown and translate it to a unified symbol)

handleClick calls transformSymbol (for example) passing the label '+' and handleKeyDown calls transformSymbol (passing the event key) for example code 57, in this case transformSymbol is going to get '+' or 57 and your transformSymbol will return '+' always that is the common language that I will try to send to "calculate" function passing the '+' at the end that is going to handle the calculation and state management

The way that the operation will clear something after a calculation is based on the state and not the multiple handlers, if you click on a button with the symbol = or keypress '=' both will be set the state to isAnswer = true but this will be managed in "calculation" function when it receives the "=" transformed language

Your current operation state will dictate what you will do with the numbers if it is equal you show the result if its another operation is show the result and assign the new current operation
